# 2d array python print each row with square brackets still attached python

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

I have a matrix:

```
m = [
[5, 1, 7, 5],
[2, 4, 9, 5],
[3, 4, 5, 5],
[3, 4, 6, 7]]
```

When I print the matrix, the output is:

```
[[5, 1, 7, 5], [2, 4, 9, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5], [3, 4, 6, 7]]
```

How do you print this matrix to where the output is the same as the initial input
like this below:

```
[
[5, 1, 7, 5],
[2, 4, 9, 5],
[3, 4, 5, 5],
[3, 4, 6, 7]
]
```

Most answers I see erase the square brackets when printing.  Is there a way to do this and still have the square brackets there like I did when I first defined the 2D array?

Comment: It's certainly doable. But wonder what's the use case here...

Comment: yeah I might be splitting hairs with this... just an aesthetic thing for my mind LOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will be dependent on your console/IDE.  You could try to use [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html).

```
>>> m
[[5, 1, 7, 5], [2, 4, 9, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5], [3, 4, 6, 7]]

>>> pprint(m, width=40)
[[5, 1, 7, 5],
 [2, 4, 9, 5],
 [3, 4, 5, 5],
 [3, 4, 6, 7]]
```

Attempt at a more general approach of determining the width (not sure how this would fair for other nested lists, but works here):

```
pprint(m, width=len(str(m))-1)
```

Comment: Couldn't you substitute / replace `], [` with `],\n[` - works for any width / sized numbers??

Comment: @MrR You could do that, say `print(',\n'.join([str(i) for i in m]))` (and optionally add back the leading and trailing bracket).  This feels a little more intensive to me, but works here and preserves the square shape